# I am struggling to insert data into a combobox with an int[]

Tags: java, netbeans

Hi i am trying to fill my combo bow with data from my database and i have made a methoed to populate it

```
ublic class Populate {
    private ConnectDB db = new ConnectDB(); // instantiates the object db
    PropertyList  prop = new PropertyList();
    TenantList ten = new TenantList();

    public int [] populatecmbTenant(){
        ArrayList<Integer> cmbTenant = new ArrayList<>();
        ResultSet rs = db.getResults("SELECT TenantId FROM tblTenant");
        try {
            while (rs.next()){
                cmbTenant.add(rs.getInt("TenantID"));

                }


        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Populate.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        int[] returnID = new int [cmbTenant.size()];
                for (int i = 0; i < cmbTenant.size(); i++) {
                    returnID[i] = cmbTenant.get(i);

    }
                return returnID;
}}
```

but then when i go to set the values into my combo bow int the initcomponents();
it wont let this is the error "no suitable constructor found for DefualtComboBoxModel(int[])
the code i used to populate it was

```
DefaultComboBoxModel Tenant = new DefaultComboBoxModel(pop.populatecmbTenant());
```

can anyone help me fix it

Comment: how do covert a int[] to an int ?

Comment: Make it an `Integer []` instead of `int []`. Need to use the class form of the primitive.

Answer (score 1):

The constructor you want of the DefaultComboBoxModel is described as the following:

```
Constructs a DefaultComboBoxModel object initialized with an array of objects.
```

Normal int is not an object in java so you need Integer[] as the returned array.